# I am getting Datatype mismatch error due to blank cells in DataGridView

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a code that takes data from excel to `DataGridView` and then from there saves on to an access database. I think my code is good but i keep getting

> "Datatype mismatch"

I believe it is because of the the blank cells in the DataGridView. Can someone please suggest a different approach? Thanks

```
private void btn_sal2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection cnEMP2 = new OleDbConnection();
        cnEMP2.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\SWFAL\Desktop\McDat2019.mdb";
        cnEMP2.Open();
        using (OleDbCommand cmdEMP2 = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow EMPRow in this.dgvsal.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= EMPRow.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (EMPRow.Cells[i].Value != null || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[i].Value)))
                    {
                        cmdEMP2.Connection = cnEMP2;
                        string qryEMP = "UPDATE Salinity2 set Texture='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[1].Value) + "', EC='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[2].Value) + "', Cl='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[3].Value) + "', NO3N='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[4].Value) + "', pH='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[5].Value) + "', CO3='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[6].Value) + "', HCO3='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[7].Value) + "', Volume='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[8].Value) + "', [NH4-N]='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[9].Value) + "', Na='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[10].Value) + "', Ca='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[11].Value) + "', Mg='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[12].Value) + "', K='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[13].Value) + "', SO4='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[14].Value) + "', Boron='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[15].Value) + "', [ICAP-P]='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[16].Value) + "', Fe='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[17].Value) + "', Zn='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[18].Value) + "', Cu='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[19].Value) + "', Mn='" + Convert.ToString(EMPRow.Cells[20].Value) + "' where LabID=" + Convert.ToInt32(EMPRow.Cells[0].Value) + " ";
                        cmdEMP2.CommandText = qryEMP;
                        cmdEMP2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmdEMP2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

            }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to insert null values into a non nullable field in access? Impossible for me to say without having access to your db or your dataset.

Comment: your code is not good from the design stand point. If you load your data from Excel, use ACE.OleDb driver to fill dataset. You can display your items in DGV via DataView. But you then can save it from the DataTable you fill. Basically, don't use your DGV as data stage point. Use what was designed for this - dataTables

Comment: Gluing data into a string to make a query is a very dangerous, tedious, error prone and outdated way to create queries.  NET DB provider objects as well as ORMs will do all of that.

Comment: Right after qryEMP , put MessageBox.Show(qryEMP);  Then the query that is generated and run it in SQL.  If you can’t figure it out, troubleshoot it in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

To load from Excel into a dataset, try the following.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection ;
                System.Data.DataSet DtSet ;
                System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand ;
                MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
                MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
                MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
                MyConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }
   }
}
```

To export from datagridview to MS Access.

```
private void btnExportToAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport accessExport = new             
                Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport();
                accessExport.DataSource = Spire.DataExport.Common.ExportSource.DataTable;
                accessExport.DataTable = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
                accessExport.DatabaseName = @"..\..\ToMdb.mdb";
                accessExport.TableName = "ExportFromDatatable";
                accessExport.SaveToFile();
            }
```